# mongodb and querying with longer text

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

fellow programmers!
Is there any way to search for a longer text like "I want a big cola and beef with this fish" to find somehow correlated objects in collection that are as 
a) sub array of 'tags' like "cola", "beef"
b) we have a text field with something text like "Mostly ordered fish is a tuna"

To summarise, is there a way to sorta partially match multi-word input with some objects in the collection.

I know I could do a split on input string and have array of words and do the same with objects in collection sadly I'm not sure if I will always have a 100% sure match like beef == beef I think there will be like beef == beefed

I hope my question is clear enough ;)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would **split words** inside an array, then **build** a dynamic **regex** and finally make a **mongodb request**.

---

The keyword for `regex` in mongoose is `$regex`

To create a dynamic `regex`, here is an example:

```
new RegExp(pattern1+'|'+pattern2, 'gi')
```